# Fetch values for different rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, self

I am using MySql and please refer **http://postimg.org/image/waso0lsnf/** to see my table structure. 
I want to fetch the `department_id` which `enduser_to_department = Y` as well as `department_to_enduser  = Y`.
Value may be available in different row for the same `department_id.`

I have tried following way but it's working for the single row.

```
SELECT `departments`.`department_id`, `departments`.`department`
FROM `custom_forms_departments` , `departments`
WHERE departments.department_id = custom_forms_departments.department_id
AND (`custom_forms_departments`.`enduser_to_department` = 'Y'
OR  `custom_forms_departments`.`department_to_enduser` = 'Y')
GROUP BY `departments`.`department_id` 
ORDER BY departments.department_id DESC
```

http://postimg.org/image/waso0lsnf/

**Edit : added image from URL.**
[image]

Comment: Theres no attached Schema/Structure... we need more information to go on.

Comment: Please check http://postimg.org/image/waso0lsnf/ as per edited question.

Comment: So what SQL have you tried?

Comment: @pratik: from the posted rows, which of the rows are you expecting as result?

Comment: @pratik: You can attach image directly selecting from your system. `postimg` site is showing some *vulgar* ads besides your image

Comment: @RavinderReddy I guess his reputation doesnt allow him.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: @RavinderReddy

Check department_id 1 
If `enduser_to_department` = 'Y' id = 6
and `department_to_enduser` = 'Y' = id 32

It should return department_id 1 in my result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT `department_id`
    FROM   `custom_forms_departments` 
    WHERE  `enduser_to_department` = 'Y'
    AND    `department_to_enduser` = 'Y'
    GROUP BY `departments`.`department_id` 
    ORDER BY departments.department_id DESC
```

Edit: No join now.

I just changed `OR` for `AND` since you want them both to be **'Y'**, and changed  the join.

Comment: It's not working when Y is contain in different row for the same department_id for enduser_to_department and department_to_enduser.

Comment: @pratik Ok, and why do you need the join? what does the other table contains and why you need the department_id from there, and not from custom_form_departments? try my new attempt.

Comment: @Nighunter22

It will return true only if the same row of table contain Y for single department_id both values `enduser_to_department` = 'Y'   AND    `department_to_enduser` = 'Y'.

But I want to display records even if department id 1 contains value Y for both columns in different column.

Answer (score 0):

in where clause you can specify condition

enduser_to_departmen = 'Y' and department_to_enduser = 'Y'

instead of group by u can use distinct

Comment: I have tried this but need to fetch the records with different row for the same department_id which have value "Y"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve ur problem

SELECT `departments`.`department_id`, `departments`.`department`
FROM `custom_forms_departments` 
left join `departments`
WHERE departments.department_id = custom_forms_departments.department_id
AND (`custom_forms_departments`.`enduser_to_department` = 'Y'
OR  `custom_forms_departments`.`department_to_enduser` = 'Y')
ORDER BY departments.department_id DESC